# Function search bing in google sheets or excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, bing-search

Before I used google sheets to search bing to see if a certain email address was to be found in a certain domain.

=IFERROR(IF(VALUE(substitute(importXML("https://www.bing.com/search?q=site:"&ENCODEURL(D3)&"+"&C3, "//*[@class='sb_count']"), " results", ""))>0, TRUE),FALSE)

where d3 is the domain and c3 the email address. Back working with google sheets and excel, can somebody point me in the right direction for both google sheets and excel?

Tried to modify this sheet, but could not get it to work, but when searching in bing

site:hello.com +(evan.holly@hello.com) I get 2 answers.

I remember that I needed an api for asking google but not bing at that time, but maybe that is a problem. But single queries is usually accepted, just some thought.